# Find rows where one of 2 cols contains any value from a third split column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Pandas Dataframe like this:

```
A           B           C
-------------------------
A. b.       b. d.       a
c.          c.          d
a. k.       b.          b
a.          b.          a, B
```

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['A. b.', 'c.', 'a. k.', 'a.'],
    'B': ['b. d.', 'c.', 'b.', 'b.'],
    'C': ['a', 'd', 'b', 'a, B']
})
```

I want to select all rows where A or B contain any value from C. Here, the result would be:

```
A           B           C
-------------------------
A. b.       b. d.       a
a. k.       b.          b
a.          b.          a, B
```

All cells contain values in a simple delimited format (can use `split`).

I've tried:

```
df[df['A'].str.contains(df['C'].split(','))]
```

But no success so far.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from your sample output that your comparisons are case-insensitive:

```
mask = pd.DataFrame({
           'AB': (df.A + df.B).str.lower().map(set),
           'C': df.C.str.split(',').map(set)
       }).apply(lambda row: bool(row['AB'].intersection(row['C'])), axis=1)

df[mask].reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

**Description:**

Combine columns `A` and `B` and convert each cell value to a set of the characters it contains. Split column `C` delimited values to a set as well and check if the intersection between `AB` and `C` is empty or not, use the resulting bool series as a mask for your original dataframe.

---

**Timings:**

```
def f():
    mask = pd.DataFrame({
               'AB': (df.A + ' ' + df.B).str.lower().map(set),
               'C': df.C.str.split(',').map(set)
           }).apply(lambda row: bool(row['AB'].intersection(row['C'])), axis=1)

    df[mask].reset_index(drop=True)

%timeit f
```

Output:

```
27.4 ns ± 0.483 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to select all rows where A or B contain any value from C

You can use [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) here. Here is a small example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,4,1], [2,5,4], [3,6,7]], columns=['a','b','c'])
df1.loc[df1['a'].isin(df1['c'])]

#output:

    a   b   c
0   1   4   1
```

The reason why this returns the row is does is because the value `1` is in column `c`.

Comment: This did not work for me: 

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A': ['A. b.', 'c.', 'a. k.', 'a.'],
        'B': ['b. d.', 'c.', 'b.', 'b.'],
        'C': ['a', 'd', 'b', 'a, B']
    })

using your code: 

    df.loc[df['C'].isin(df['A'])]

Comment: @Zubo, well sure - there are `.` in your example here in the comments. you would have to remove those. because `'a' != 'a.'` in your question you have demonstrated the knowledge of `.split()`

Comment: I have also tried ``df.loc[df['C'].str.split(',').isin(df['A'])]``, which returns ``TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'``. Also, I cannot see from your example how I can include the condition that anything in ``C`` can be in A *or* C. I'd happily upvote your answer back again if I could use it.

Comment: @Zubo. Can you edit your question then? I'm confused as to what you need. However, if you're question is answered by another post then you can just leave it be and accept the other answer